# Looking for the correct Syntax for type hidden when passing an array? PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to have the $x change as the value of x changes in the loop. What is the correct syntax to do this?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {?>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1['.$x.']" value="
      <?=$v_resource_id; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array2['.$x.']" value="
      <?=$v_category_name; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array3['.$x.']" value="
      <?=$v_website_name; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array4['.$x.']" value="
      <?=$v_webaddress; ?>"/>
   <?php 
   } 
   ?>
```

Comment: `... a_line_array1['<?= $x; ?>'] ...` ?

Comment: Unclear, can you edit and make it so we can understand what you're trying to do here?

Comment: You forgot to wrap server-side PHP tags around your use of `$x`.

Comment: Why are you giving all the inputs the same name?

Comment: @Barmar : He's building a multidimensional array. When you want to build a multidimensional array in HTML, you will state the key with bracket, like so `<input name="key_name[]" value="1">` which will result in your $_POST of a key called "key_name" with multiple values.

Comment: @Preciel I understand how array inputs work. The problem is he's not giving a different name to the different arrays, they're all named `a_line_array1`. They should be `a_line_array1[$x]`, `a_line_array2[$x]`, and so on.

Comment: Oh... Indeed, didn't noticed... He's just overwriting the value over and over that way... Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You for loop needs to look like this :

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {?>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?php  echo $x; ?>]" value="
      <?php  echo $v_resource_id; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?php  echo $x; ?>]" value="
      <?php  echo $v_resource_id; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?php  echo $x; ?>]" value="
      <?php  echo $v_resource_id; ?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?php  echo $x; ?>]" value="
      <?php  echo $v_resource_id; ?>"/>
   <?php 
   } 
 ?>
```

I suggest you learn how to concatenate values in PHP and how to mix PHP and HTML.

Comment: I derped. But let's admit the world would look less ugly and confusing without them.

Comment: The primary issue with PHP's short tags is that PHP managed to choose a tag `<?` that was used by another syntax, XML. Although `<?` causes conflicts with xml, `<?=` does not. To sum up, `<?` is bad, prefer `<?php`, but `<?=` is valid and don't causes any conflicts. Please avoid suggestions based on broken knowledge... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a code. please user PHP tag

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++):
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1['.$x.']" value="'.$v_resource_id.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1['.$x.']" value="'.$v_category_name.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1['.$x.']" value="'.$v_website_name.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1['.$x.']" value="'.$v_webaddress.'"/>';

endfor;
```

Comment: If you're going to use only PHP, then why not use curly brackets?

Comment: That's actually slightly *odd* syntax; you'd *generally* use the `<?php for(...): ?> ... <?php endfor; ?>` style when breaking out of PHP into HTML and the `<?php for() { ... } ?>` when using `echo` - so while the OPs original syntax is odd for using `{ ... }` and breaking out of PHP yours is odd for the exact opposite reason - won't stop it working but if you're going to call the OP out for it...

Answer (score 0):

Update from Julien Lachal's answer:

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {?>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?=$x?>]" value="<?=$v_resource_id=?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?=$x=?>]" value="<?=$v_resource_id?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?$x=?>]" value="<?=$v_resource_id=?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="a_line_array1[<?=$x=?>]" value="<?=$v_resource_id=?>"/>
   <?php 
   } 
 ?>
```